# Append/Concatenate & sort two Numpy matrixes

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, matrix

I have one input array with a shape of [1,500] in the form:

> [[0][1][2] ... [499]]

To be combined with a random output array with a shape of [1,500] as:

> [[22][16][11] ... [51]]

I have attempted using either concatenate or append like so (1 at a time):

```
inAndout = np.append(soloInput, outputMatrix, axis=1) #or:
inAndout = np.append(soloInput, outputMatrix, axis=1) #Commented 1 out each time
```

The output from both is fairly good with a form when print(inAndOut):

> [[0   22][1   16][2   11] ... [499   51]] #Notice no ',' only spacing between added arrays

When I then use:

```
sortedInput = np.sort(inAndout, axis=0)
```

It results in:

> [[**0   11**][**1   16**][**2   22**] ... [**499   51**]] #It sorts both inputs and outputs

Also when I use axis=1 it results in an unsorted matrix.

What I would like is for it to just sort based off outputs or just sort based off inputs like so:

> [[**0**   22][**1**   16][**2**   22] ... [**499**   51]] #Sorted by inputs
>   [[2   **11**][1   **16**][0   **22**] ... [499   **51**]] #Sorted by outputs

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The two lines you show are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `argsort` to return the indices that sorts either the input or the output and then reorder all columns with the indices:

Sort by input:

```
inAndout[inAndout[:,0].argsort(),:]
```

Sort by output:

```
inAndout[inAndout[:,1].argsort(),:]
```

---

*Example*:

```
inAndout = np.array([[0, 22],[1, 16],[2, 11],[499, 51]])

inAndout

#array([[  0,  22],
#       [  1,  16],
#       [  2,  11],
#       [499,  51]])

inAndout[inAndout[:,0].argsort(),:]

#array([[  0,  22],
#       [  1,  16],
#       [  2,  11],
#       [499,  51]])

inAndout[inAndout[:,1].argsort(),:]

#array([[  2,  11],
#       [  1,  16],
#       [  0,  22],
#       [499,  51]])
```